# Flutter Firebase Storage 0.5.0 upload file and video error

Tags: firebase, file, flutter, upload

**What I want to do:** Upload a file and a video with Firebase Storage 0.5.0 and return url.

**What current problem is:** I can upload file and image with Firebase storage 0.5.0, but I can't  return url. I also see my file and video uploaded in Firebase storage in Firebase console.

**My code:**

```
Future<String> _uploadFile(Reference ref, File file,
      [SettableMetadata metadata]) async {
    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(file, metadata);
    uploadTask.whenComplete(() async {
      try {} catch (onError) {
        print("Error");
      }
    });
    final url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    return url;
  }

 Future<String> uploadVideo(File video,
      {String refName, SettableMetadata metadata}) async {
    metadata = SettableMetadata(contentType: 'video/mp4');
    final name = refName != null ? refName : path.basename(video.path);
    final ref = _VideoRef.child(name);
    return _uploadFile(ref, video, metadata);
  } 

Future<File> downloadImage(String imageUrl, String savePath) async {
    final ref = _storage.ref(imageUrl);
    var file = File(savePath);
    await ref.writeToFile(file);
    return file;
  }
```

**What the console told me:**

> FirebaseException (Firebase_storage/object-not-found). No object exist in desired reference.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 uploadTask.whenComplete(() async {
      try {
     url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
      } catch (onError) {
        print("Error");
      }
    });
```

When the future completes, call `getDownloadURL()` to get the url.

Comment: That doesn't work and app crash.                                                                                     Future<String> _uploadFile(Reference ref, File file,
      [SettableMetadata metadata]) async {
    String url = "";
    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(file, metadata);
    uploadTask.whenComplete(() async {
      try {
        url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
      } catch (onError) {
        print("Error");
      }
    });
    return url;
  }

Comment: I am getting error message "The getter '_value' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: _value. "DateTime.difference (dart:core-patch/date_patch.dart:201:54).  But I can see that my file and video are uploaded in Firebase storage.

Comment: Where are u using datetime class in your code?

Comment: The error above is not related to the code i gave you, please add the code in which you use the DateTime class

Comment: I am using it here:                                                                                                DateTime dateTimeParser(object) {
  if (object is String) {
    return DateTime.parse(object);
  } else if (object is int) {
    return DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(object);
  } else {
    throw "dateTimeParser() error object is neither String or int";
  }
}   and when I map data.                                                   Video.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> map, {this.id, this.user}) {
    createdAt = dateTimeParser(map['createdAt']);
  }

Comment: check if object is null

Comment: After Video or file is uploaded to firebase storage it is null here:                                 static Future<String> createTempOutputPath(String fileExtension) async {
    Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    String fileName =
        DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString() + ".$fileExtension";
    return File("${tempDir.path}/$fileName").

Comment: What is null here? Please ask it as a different question, the answer here solves the original problem of this question

Comment: This can be closed.

Comment: if the answer helped you please mark it as correct and upvote it, thank you

Comment: Yes, I have also found a null value in ServerValue.timestamp. But will create a new question for that.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers